# How to calculate Cycles Per Element(CPE) of a loop?

Tags: pipeline

I am working on one of the problems of my Computer System's text book.

For the problem, I have been given a loop shown below, and latency and issue rate of operations such as Integer add, Integer multiply, Float add, Float multiply.

```
int out1, input1;

float out2, input2;

for (i=0; i< length; i++){
   out1 = input1 + array1[i];
   out2 = out1 + array2[i];
}
```

I have to calculate the Cycles Per Element(CPE) for the loop above. I am completely lost and not sure how to get started.  Could someone please suggest how to approach  this problem, and what role latency and issue rate will play?

Comment: Do you mean Carrier Phase Estimation?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?